# How to Toggle Class on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on hover it works fine but on click the class remains 
I would like to removed the border after clicking another image with the same element

```
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();    
});
```

like how on hover works

```
$('img').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cqzoh36h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this remove boder of all img onclick and assigns class border to clicked element

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  $('img').removeClass('border');
  $(this).toggleClass('border');
});
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #333
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/15/007Squirtle_XY_anime.png/revision/latest?cb=20140916184418" />
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/15/007Squirtle_XY_anime.png/revision/latest?cb=20140916184418" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove class from other `img` tags except the clicked

```js
// keep reference to all img tags collection
var $ele = $('img').on('click', function(e) {
  // use addClass to add class, use toggleClass if you want to toggle on each click
  $(this).addClass('active');
  // filter out img except clicked and
  // remove the class
  $ele.not(this).removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #333
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/15/007Squirtle_XY_anime.png/revision/latest?cb=20140916184418" />
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/15/007Squirtle_XY_anime.png/revision/latest?cb=20140916184418" />
```

With [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method it's working because the callback is called on both `mousenter` and `mouseleave` events, actually its short handler for that.